# Retrieving nonetype object is not iterable error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code which sends video frames from client to server. I am reading frames from a folder in the rate of five frames per second and then send the frames to server. I am retrieving error while running the code.

```
INTERVAL_DELAY = 0.25
SERVER_A_ADDRESS = "tcp://localhost:5555"
SERVER_A_TITLE = "Server A"
context = zmq.Context()
socket_server_a = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
socket_server_a.connect(SERVER_A_ADDRESS)
destination = {
 "currentSocket": socket_server_a,
 "currentServersTitle": SERVER_A_TITLE}
running = True
frame_count = 0
def send_frame(frame, frame_count):
 global destination, running
  try:
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (224, 224))
    encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
    destination["currentSocket"].send(jpg_as_text)
  except Exception as Error:
    print(Error)
    running = False
def main():
  global destination, running, frame_count
  filenames = [img for img in glob.glob("video-frames/*.jpg")]
  fps = 5
  interval = int(1 / fps)
  while running:
    filenames = sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime) or filenames.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    for img in filenames:
        frame = cv2.imread(img)
        frame_count += 1
        threading.Thread(target=send_frame, args=(frame, frame_count)).start()
        time.sleep(interval)
    time.sleep(INTERVAL_DELAY)
  destination["currentSocket"].close()
  destination["pendingSocket"].close()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Error retrieving:

```
 for img in filenames:
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, clearly, `filenames` is None.

Comment: What did you expect `sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime) or filenames.sort(key=os.path.getctime)` to evaluate to?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out @ThierryLathuille, it was not reading the file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sorted(lst)` is a function that returns a new list.

`lst.sort()` sorts the list in place, and has nothing to return, so it returns `None`.

`a or b` evaluates to the first thing that allows to decide if it is truthy or falsy.

If your `filenames` list is not empty, `sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)` won't be empty, so it's considered True in boolean context. As the whole condition is certain to be `True`, `sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime) or filenames.sort(key=os.path.getctime)` evaluates to `sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)`

If `filenames` is empty, `sorted(filenames, ...)` will be the empty list, that is considered falsy. So, the second part `sort(...)` has to be evaluated to decide the whole `or` expression. It returns `None`, the truthiness of the whole is finally decided, it evaluates to the decisive value, `None`.

That's what happened in your case.

So, just remove the last part and use:

```
filenames = sorted(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)
```